# How to properly combine laravel and datatables editor

Tags: php, laravel, datatables

tell me how can I add a server-side datatable script to the controller method that I am accessing via ajax so that it can be accessed via routing. Everything else seems to be right. But I cant figure out how to do the server side correctly in laravel.
I tried to add the datatable backend to the controller method. The variable $ db had to be made global, maybe this is wrong, I don't know. And got the following errors. Also I think the routing needs to be fixed too, but I don't know how.

route

```
Route::get('/service/formats', [FormatController::class, 'index'])->name('service.formats');
Route::get('/service/formats/load', [FormatController::class, 'getAllJson'])->name('service.formats.getall');
```

Controller

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Format;
use DataTables\Editor;
use DataTables\Editor\Field;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class FormatController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('service.format.index');
    }

    public function getAllJson()
    {
        global $db;
        Editor::inst($db, 'formats', 'id')
            ->fields(
                Field::inst('id'),
                Field::inst('name')
            )
            ->process($_POST)
            ->json();
    }


}
```

js

```
<script>
    var editor; // use a global for the submit and return data rendering in the examples

    $(document).ready(function() {
        editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor( {
            ajax: "{{ route('service.formats.getall') }}",
            table: "#formats",
            fields: [ {
                label: "ID:",
                name: "ID"
            }, {
                label: "Name:",
                name: "Name"
            }
            ]
        } );

        $('#formats').DataTable( {
            dom: "Bfrtip",
            ajax: "{{ route('service.formats.getall') }}",
            columns: [
                { data: "ID" },
                { data: "Name" }
            ],
            select: true,
            buttons: [
                { extend: "create", editor: editor },
                { extend: "edit",   editor: editor },
                { extend: "remove", editor: editor }
            ]
        } );
    } );
</script>
```

Errors

```
{
"message": "Call to a member function transaction() on null",
"exception": "Error",
"file": "/application/vendor/datatables.net/editor-php/Editor.php",
"line": 969,
"trace": [
    {
        "file": "/application/vendor/datatables.net/editor-php/Editor.php",
        "line": 701,
        "function": "_process",
        "class": "DataTables\\Editor",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/application/app/Http/Controllers/FormatController.php",
        "line": 26,
        "function": "process",
        "class": "DataTables\\Editor",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/application/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php",
        "line": 54,
        "function": "getAllJson",
        "class": "App\\Http\\Controllers\\FormatController",
        "type": "->"
    },
    .....and that is not all
```

Comment: When using Laravel, you never use `include`, `include_once`, `require` or `require_once` anymore... you just use `use`, it will automatically make it available for you... Learn PHP so it is easier for you...

Comment: @matiaslauriti I do not use include in laravel, it is a server-side script that is used in datatable. And I don't understand how to add it correctly to the laravel controller method. This is the question, that is, how to change it for laravel

Comment: You have an include in your code. no? If you used composer to install the datatables package, its not needed, the namespace is autoloaded.

Comment: @GertB. This is the server-side datatable code that I used in native php. Now I want to transfer this to laravel. Namely, I thought to transfer this to the controller method getAllJson()

Comment: Suggestion: You can [edit] your question to provide a better title - one which is specific to the problem you are facing.

Comment: @andrewjames see please i tried to do this

Comment: OK - but my note was just a suggestion that you may want to provide a more specific _title_. You didn't actually do that...

Comment: @andrewjames yes, I changed the title too

Comment: @andrewjames I don’t know how to write the title more specifically. But I tried to describe my problem more specifically in the description.